# Size of content within bootstrap modal varies depending on the time of load

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, google-api, bootstrap-modal

I'm using a bootstrap modal to show a google api chart. The data for the chart is loaded when the page is loaded, and the modal contains the chart at page load.

At first I just showed the modal when the page loaded, and everything looked fine. Then I added a button to show the modal only when requested. Nothing else changed. Now the chart is tiny within the modal.

All code is the same, except I added a button and an onclick event on the button, showing the modal.

Any thoughts?

There is a CSS snippet that changes the modal from the default:

```
.modal
{
    height:80%;
    width:80%;
    margin-left: -40%; 
}
```

Here is the html for the modal

```
 <div id="chartsModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="chartsModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="chartsModalLabel">Evolution of number of X</h3>
    </div> 
    <div id="number_of_evolution" class="span11" style="height:40em"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost fixed the problem but a little bit remains. I don't know exactly what caused it but I decided to create the chart when the button is pressed and everything looks great now. Seems like the more sensible thing to do anyways :)

But if I open the modal, then do a page refresh, and open the modal again, the chart is again tiny. Odd.

EDIT: Latter is also fixed, by waiting until the modal has completely finished load before drawing. The second time that chart is drawn, it seems to take a shorter time (even though there was a full page refresh in between, causing it to be wrongly sized):

$('#chartsModal').on('shown', function () { ...